# Django and ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to run a jquery function on link click and return a modified html. This is the code:

> Html

```
                      <li>
                        <a runat="server" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick= "myFunction( '{{ playlist.name }}')" >{{ playlist.name }}</a> 
                      </li>
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
});

var myFunction = function(playlist){
    console.log(playlist);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/select_playlist/',
        data: {
            'playlist': playlist
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('This is not executing');
            console.log(data);
            $('#to_replace').html(data);
        },
    });
}
```

> Views.py:

```
def select_playlist(request):

    playlist = request.GET.get('playlist', None)
    selected_playlist = Playlist.objects.get( name  = playlist)
    print(playlist)
    print(selected_playlist)
    html = render_to_string('Play/playlist_detail_ajax.html', {'sel_playlist': selected_playlist})
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

It works fine right until the `ajax` function, i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with that `success` function.

Comment: You should look in your browser's dev tools to see what the server is sending you. Most likely, there is an error because you don't seem to be sending a value for playlist from your JS.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm getting the data from `myFunction` - it's sending me the name of the playlist and it gets to the views function because i can see it printed in django. also the `html` seems to be returned, it's somewhere broken on the way back, between what my view sends and what the `js` receives - either the view does not return or i'm not catching the `httpresponse` correctly

Comment: i can see what the view returns in dev tools - so it's somewhere in the javascript what i'm not doing right

Comment: Well, one obvious issue is that you've specified `dataType: 'json',` but your view is returning HTML.

Comment: i just came to this same conclusion, 10 secs ago and that s why it was probably not even printing anything. Thank you!